# Display MS Access data in a JTable

Tags: java

I'm unable to display data from MS Access to a Java `JTable`. The stack trace is attached at the bottom.

```
public  void ShowData() throws SQLException {

    conn = LoginClass.ConnectDB();
    String sql2 = "Select * From TEST";

    Vector col = new Vector();
    Vector dat = new Vector();
    col.add("ID");
    col.add("Stu1_Name");
    rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery(sql2);
    dat.clear();

    if(rs.next()) {
        Vector v = new Vector();

        v.add(rs.getString("ID").trim());
        v.add(rs.getString("StuName").trim());
        dat.addElement(v);
        }

    jTable1.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(col,dat));
}
```

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Vector
    at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.justifyRows(DefaultTableModel.java:268)
    at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.setDataVector(DefaultTableModel.java:224)
    at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.<init>(DefaultTableModel.java:159)
    at assignment.TEST.ShowData(TEST.java:51)
    at assignment.TEST.formWindowOpened(TEST.java:120)
    at assignment.TEST.access$000(TEST.java:25)
    at assignment.TEST$1.windowOpened(TEST.java:76)
    at java.awt.Window.processWindowEvent(Window.java:2048)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.processWindowEvent(JFrame.java:296)
    at java.awt.Window.processEvent(Window.java:2009)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: "java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Vector" - there's your answer.

Comment: The constructor for DefaultTableModel that accepts 2 vectors is expecting the second vector to contain Strings. You are not putting Strings into the dat vector.

Comment: bro i even tried passing string value to dat but it still doesn't work

Comment: so if i pass string to dat it should be like this rite:  dat.add(rs.getString("ID").trim());
            dat.add(rs.getString("StuName").trim());

Comment: must i convert the dat vector to string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On this line of code:

```
jTable1.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(col,dat));
```

the arguments to the `DefaultTableModel` constructor are swapped. The column names should be the second argument.